# Get most common combinations across multiple rows based on three identifiers

Tags: r

| GameID | PlayID | Route | Side |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | Curl | R |
| 001 | 1 | Out | L |
| 001 | 1 | Go | L |
| 001 | 2 | Flat | R |
| 001 | 2 | Out | R |
| 002 | 1 | Corner | R |
| 002 | 1 | Post | R |

What I would like to have happen is to get the most common combinations of Routes to one side that occur and have a count. I'd like to have it look something like this:

| Combinations | n |
| --- | --- |
| Out/Go - L | 41 |
| Corner/Post - R | 33 |

I'm having some trouble getting the `dplyr` right for this, here is what I've tried so far:

```
df2 <- df %>%
    group_by(GameID, PlayID) %>%
    mutate(n = n()) %>%
    group_by(Route, Side)
```

But I am a bit lost on how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of how you can do that through concatenating the routing options;

```
# Loading Required libraries
library(dplyr)

# Creating sample data
example <- read.table(text ='
GameID|PlayID|Route|Side
001|1|Curl|R
001|1|Out|L
001|1|Go|L
001|2|Flat|R
001|2|Out|R
002|1|Corner|R
002|1|Post|R',header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = "|")

example %>%
  # Grouping by Game, player and side
  group_by(GameID, PlayID, Side) %>%
  # Combining all the routes made into single column
  summarise(Combinations = paste(Route, collapse ='/'), .groups = "drop") %>%
  # Concatenating Side to the route
  mutate(Combinations = paste0(Combinations, " - ", Side)) %>%
  # Grouping by the combination to get # of its occurances
  group_by(Combinations) %>%
  count()
```

Comment: How would I do this if my dataframe/table is thousands of rows? Is there a way to convert that to the format you showed at the ```read.table``` portion?

Comment: For sure this is just an example. From the example you have given looks like your data is called df so ignore then read.table step and instead of example replace it with df and it should work.